# Разное значение ST_Intersects в mysql в зависимости от SRID

Tags: mysql

запрос

```
SELECT
    (
        ST_Intersects(
            ST_PolygonFromText('POLYGON((-90 -180, 90 -180, 90 180, -90 180, -90 -180))',4326),
            ST_PolygonFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 0 5, 5 5, 5 0, 0 0))',4326)
        )
    )
```

возвращает 0 (False), хотя явно же видно, что полигоны пересекаются.
а тот же запрос, но без значения SRID=4326

```
    SELECT
(
    ST_Intersects(
        ST_PolygonFromText('POLYGON((-90 -180, 90 -180, 90 180, -90 180, -90 -180))'),
        ST_PolygonFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 0 5, 5 5, 5 0, 0 0))')
    )
)
```

возвращает 1 (True). Что не так с SRID?

Comment: С чего ты решил, что на глобусе большой полигон захватит именно то полушарие, где лежит маленький?

Comment: с того, что я беру весь глобус

Comment: Полигон не может взять весь глобус... хоть что-то, да останется снаружи. Но главное - это надо смотреть в доках на постгис,- нужно чётко понять, как выбирается сторона полигона при таких больших размерах. Я не смотрел..

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Подумал, что строится этот полигон как линия, добавил промежуточные точки ST_PolygonFromText('POLYGON((-180 -90, 180 -90, 0 90, 180 90, -180 90, 0 -90, -180 -90))', 4326, 'axis-order=long-lat') и всё заработало